# python split string number in digits

Tags: python, regex, string, list

Hi I would like to split the following string "1234" in ['1', '2', '3', '4'] in python.

My current approach is using re module

```
import re
re.compile('(\d)').split("1234")
['', '1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '']
```

But i get some extra empty strings. I am not an expert in regular expressions, what could be a proper regular expression in python to accomplish my task?

Please give me some advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function, like this

```
>>> list("1234")
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

The `list` function iterates the string, and creates a new list with all the characters in it.

Comment: Also, if you have a string with non-numeric elements, you can use list comprehension like so `[i for i in "1234abcd" if i.isdigit()]`

Comment: great, this works perfectly. I didn't know that is posible create a list from string. This is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are by default character lists:

```
>>> nums = "1234"
>>> for i in nums:
...     print i
... 
1
2
3
4
>>> nums[:-1]
'123'
```